# How to connect Mule application to SQL Server with Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, mule, mulesoft, mssql-jdbc

I have SQL Server installed on my PS. I can connect to it using Windows Authentication and SQL Authentication using SQL Server Management Studio. But, when I try to connect it from Mule it's always a connection error.

Things I've tried so far:

- Used default option provided by MuleSoft for SQL Server.
- Tried turning my firewall off.
- Tried integretaedSecurity=true.
- Tried Generic connection and provide my own JDBC URL

No luck so far. Any help please?

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70968135/edit) your question to include the full and complete connection error - as text, not screenshots. It would also be helpful to show the code you're trying to use to connect, anonymising the server and username/password details as required, since there could be errors in your connection string/URL.

Comment: Exact Mule version and database connector? And what is the operating system where the Mule server is deployed? By the way it is not called MuleSoft, that's the company name.

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure that the DLL sqljdbc_auth.dll is in the path of execution for Mule. Note that integrated authentications will work only when Mule is executing in a Windows OS. It will not work if deployed to Linux, CloudHub or Runtime Fabric.

Full instructions: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-use-Windows-Authentication-in-Database-Connector-with-Microsoft-SQL-Server-in-Mule4

Answer (score 1):

It will be good if you can provide the exact error.

But mean while,

Try enabling TCP port in the system.

Below are the steps to enable TCP (in local machine).

Open the 'Sql Server Configuration Manager' application.
In the left pane, go to 'SQL Server Network Configuration' -> 'Protocols for [instance-name]'
Right-click on 'TCP/IP' and select 'enable'.

Restart the 'SQL Server ([instance-name])' windows service or restart your machine.